# If $ T^2=T$ and $T(1)=T(1+x)=4x^2$, what is the characteristic polynomial of $T$?

Tags: linear-transformations

I'm given this question:  $T$ is a linear transformation that satisfies $$T^2=T$$ and $$T(1)=T(1+x)=4x^2,$$ and I need to find its characteristic polynomial.
I tried plugging in $1$ and $1+x$ in $$T^2=T$$ and I found that $$T(x^2)=2x^2$$ and with that I tried to find representing matrix according to the basis $${1,1+x ,x^2}$$ but I keep getting contradicting results. Is that the right approach?

Edit: $$T:R2[x] > R2[x]$$

Comment: What's the dimension of the domain of the transformation?

Comment: its T with both the domain and the range of 2nd dgree polynomial

Comment: @user1188938 Add the domain to the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$T^2(1)=T(T(1))=T(4x^2)=4T(x^2),$$ which must be equal to $T(1)=4x^2$, so $T(x^2)=x^2$. Also $T(1)=T(1+x)=T(1)+T(x)$ which implies that $T(x)=0$. So the matrix of the transformation is $$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0&0\\ 0&0&0 \\ 1&0&1\end{pmatrix},$$ and thus the characteristic polynomial is $\operatorname{det}(A-\lambda I)=\lambda^2(1-\lambda).$